# how to pass JSX element from children to parent in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I made a layout container which has as a child as main content, toolbar, and toolbar.
toolbar and footer are dynamic parts and each container or page will have their own toolbar and footer, but layout structure is the same in all pages, so I made multiple layouts and called the related layout component in each container.
but I don't think if it's best practice or not, cause i have too many layouts right now!
so is there any way to define the layout toolbar and footer in child containers and pass them up to the layout? 
I know I can use the setState method to put them into the layout state, but I also know that putting the element in the state is not best practice, cause state is for data, not JSX elements or functions.
also, another way that I thought, was putting toolbar and footer using pure javascript using innerHtml of layout toolbar and footer wrapper, but it would be real DOM, not virtual DOM, so it's not best practice either!

so if there's any best practice to having dynamic layout parts based on child component, I would be happy to know them.

thanks